# Assignment of the 13C NMR spectrum of 1-(ferrocenyl)ethanol

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

The molecule in question has the following structure:

[image: Molecule]
<sub>(source: [sigmaaldrich.com](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/structure8/079/mfcd00013752.eps/_jcr_content/renditions/mfcd00013752-medium.png))</sub>

The 13C NMR is given below:

[image: NMR]

My assignments are:

23.700 ppm, -CH3

65.569 ppm, CH adjacent to the -OH

66.138/66.183 ppm; 67.924/67.977 ppm, substituted Cp carbons with protons attached

68.344 ppm; Cp carbons

94.857 ppm; Quaternary C

Are these assignments correct? The Cp carbons usually appear between 80-95 ppm but they are shifted down for some reason (I'm not sure why).

Additionally, why are the substituted Cp carbons (non-quaternary) doublets? I thought it may be due to the presence of staggered/eclipsed forms of the molecule but this would affect all the carbon environments.

Comment: Because of the chiral centre outside your ring, C2/C5 on the top Cp ring are diastereotopic (and C3/C4 too). Based on a tiny bit of internet digging, I think the shifts around 65–80 ppm are perfectly normal for ferrocenes - it surprises me more that C1 on the top Cp has such a high shift.

Comment: @orthocresol: I agree. For example, substituted $\ce C_p$ carbons in this reference (!http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.475.8371&rep=rep1&type=pdf) are reported as: $\delta$ $68.6, 69.4, 83.6$.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about the diastereotopic effect. One more question - in this case, I assigned the 68.344 ppm peak to the Cp protons purely because it had a much larger peak than the others (i.e. the 65.599 ppm peak). Is this a valid way to assign this peak even though 13C NMR integration isn't really a thing?

Comment: I think it is perfectly fair, especially in the absence of other data. You can't do 13C integration quantitatively, unless you modify the usual pulse sequence, but qualitatively there is still a link: more carbons = stronger signal. In particular it is the rate of relaxation that messes up the integration (faster relaxation = stronger signal) but between the top and bottom Cp rings I personally wouldn't expect there to be significant differences, except for the quaternary carbon of course. [Also some NOE enhancement due to decoupling but again I don't expect any real differences.]